# Creating video from DNG images with FFmpeg

Tags: video, images, ffmpeg

I'm trying to make a video from TIFF images that are DNG pictures. The problem is that the resulting video that FFmpeg creates, have a resolution lower than the original pictures

I tried with `image2` but no luck.

This is from a set of CinemaDNG images. I converted to DNG with Adobe DNG converter. Then I need to change the extension to .TIF cause FFmpeg said that no video for the original or the converted ones with .DNG extension was found. With the extensions changed to .TIF, FFmpeg is able to create a video but the resolution is super small.

Why? (Cause the original files are 2K resolution)

How can I create a video from these images?

---

This creates a video of 236MB but bad and with small resolution:

```
D:/>ffmpeg -f image2 -start_number 00101600 -i D:/temp/dng/conv2/00%3d.tif copy -qscale 1 D:/temp/dng/conv2/temp/11.avi
version N-49527-g985e93a Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
 on Feb  1 2013 18:41:39 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)
guration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-a
--enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --ena
ss --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-lib
able-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --
ibopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --
ibspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --e
bvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enabl
s --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
util      52. 17.100 / 52. 17.100
codec     54. 91.100 / 54. 91.100
format    54. 61.104 / 54. 61.104
device    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
filter     3. 35.100 /  3. 35.100
scale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
resample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
stproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
 @ 03811820] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider inc
probesize
0, image2, from 'D:/temp/dng/conv2/00%3d.tif':
ion: 00:00:02.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
eam #0:0: Video: tiff, rgb24, 256x137, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
use -q:a or -q:v, -qscale is ambiguous
:/temp/dng/conv2/temp/11.avi' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y #0, avi, to 'D:/temp/dng/conv2/temp/11.avi':
ata:
T            : Lavf54.61.104
eam #0:0: Video: tiff, rgb24, 256x137, q=2-31, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
mapping:
m #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
q] to stop, [?] for help
   9 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=   43538kB time=00:00:00.36 bitrate=990732.5kbi
  14 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=   67744kB time=00:00:00.56 bitrate=991004.4kbi
  20 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=   96792kB time=00:00:00.80 bitrate=991152.9kbi
  26 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=  125840kB time=00:00:01.04 bitrate=991231.0kbi
  32 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=  154889kB time=00:00:01.28 bitrate=991287.4kbi
  38 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=  183936kB time=00:00:01.52 bitrate=991319.5kbi
  44 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=  212983kB time=00:00:01.76 bitrate=991339.3kbi
  50 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=  242041kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate=991399.0kbi
  50 fps= 11 q=-1.0 Lsize=  242042kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate=991402.2kb

42035kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.002777
```

This creates a video of 80KB with a super slow resolution:

```
D:\temp>ffmpeg -f image2 -start_number 10105113 -i D:/temp/dng/A-CamCinemaDNGBdobeDNGConv/%03d.tif D:/temp/dng/A-CamCinemaDNGByAdobeDNGConv/temp/a.mpg
ffmpeg version N-49527-g985e93a Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb  1 2013 18:41:39 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --en
le-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-li
sm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb -
nable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger -
nable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --
able-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enab
-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 17.100 / 52. 17.100
  libavcodec     54. 91.100 / 54. 91.100
  libavformat    54. 61.104 / 54. 61.104
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 35.100 /  3. 35.100
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, image2, from 'D:/temp/dng/A-CamCinemaDNGByAdobeDNGConv/%03d.tif':
  Duration: 00:00:01.24, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: tiff, rgb24, 256x137, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File 'D:/temp/dng/A-CamCinemaDNGByAdobeDNGConv/temp/a.mpg' already exists. Ove
rite ? [y/N] Y
VBV buffer size not set, muxing may fail
Output #0, mpeg, to 'D:/temp/dng/A-CamCinemaDNGByAdobeDNGConv/temp/a.mpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.61.104
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p, 256x137, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tb
 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (tiff -> mpeg1video)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   20 fps=0.0 q=4.9 size=      54kB time=00:00:00.72 bitrate= 614.4kbits
frame=   31 fps=0.0 q=6.6 Lsize=      80kB time=00:00:01.20 bitrate= 546.1kbit
s
video:77kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 3.294791%
```

If I use the original .dng files I can't create a video:

```
D:\temp>ffmpeg -f image2 -start_number 10105113 -i D:/temp/dng/A-CamCinemaDNG/%d.DNG /tmp/a.mpg
ffmpeg version N-49527-g985e93a Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb  1 2013 18:41:39 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libg
sm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --e
nable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --e
nable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --en
able-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable
-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 17.100 / 52. 17.100
  libavcodec     54. 91.100 / 54. 91.100
  libavformat    54. 61.104 / 54. 61.104
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 35.100 /  3. 35.100
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
[image2 @ 024ac1a0] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider incr
easing probesize
[image2 @ 024ac1a0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: none):
unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
D:/temp/dng/A-CamCinemaDNG/%d.DNG: could not find codec parameters
```

Comment: From the first input, ffmpeg is telling you that the input TIFF files have a resolution of 256x137. I suspect that the problem is with whatever program you are using to convert the DNG images to TIFF; please edit into your answer whatever program that is.

Comment: In case somebody else finds this: the OP just *changed the extension*, but didn't convert the files. This is why ffmpeg (and some other software like panotools) find the embedded tiny TIFF preview at the start and use that, discarding the full-sized image that follows. The DNGs need to be converted using i.e. rawstudio or Lightroom.